# Join domain rights using powershell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2012

Is there any way (using powershell) to modify a computer account to add a user account with enough rights to add this computer to a domain?. When you use the wizard you can select an account to do this thing.
Regards

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do this with the Microsoft-provided ActiveDirectory module. It can be installed as via the RSAT package for Server 2008 R2 and above, I believe.  When you import that module, it adds a PSProvider for AD, which can be used in conjunction with the `Get-Acl` and `Set-Acl` cmdlets.

It would work very much like file system permissions in PowerShell, except you need a couple more pieces of information and use a different object type for the rule, which [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.activedirectoryaccessrule.activedirectoryaccessrule(v=vs.110).aspx) does a great job of outlining.

If you have an example computer object that already has the correct permissions applied, use the `Get-ACL` cmdlet to see what the access rules look like:

```
$acl = Get-Acl -Path 'AD:\CN=TESTCOMP-1,CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com'
$acl.Access | ft -AutoSize
```

You should be able to use this data to construct your access rule objects, add them to the ACL, and then set the acl on the path.

```
# Imagine that you already created your rule in the variable $rule1
$acl.AddAccessRule($rule1)
Set-Acl -Path 'AD:\CN=TESTCOMP-1,CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com' -AclObject $acl
```

Actual Fleshed Out Example:

If all we are doing is providing the ability for a user to re-add computer accounts to the domain, then based on [this MS KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932455), you will need to provide the user "Reset Password", "Read Account Restrictions", "Write Account Restrictions", "Validated write to DNS host name" and "Validated write to service principal name"

Each of those permissions is referred to by a specific GUID, as listed below:
Reset Password is an extended right with the Rights GUID `00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529`
Account Restrictions is a property set with the Rights GUID `4c164200-20c0-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529`
Validated DNS host name write has a Rights GUID of `72e39547-7b18-11d1-adef-00c04fd8d5cd`
Validated write to service principal name has a Rights GUID of `f3a64788-5306-11d1-a9c5-0000f80367c1`

One permission that I found was needed that was not in that KB article was the ability to read/write to the userAccountControl property.  This will only be necessary if the computer account has been removed from the domain or has been disabled in another way.  The AD GUID for userAccountControl is `bf967a68-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2`

If you don't add that permission, you could experience the following error:

```
The join operation was not successful. This could be because an existing
computer account having name “<computer name>” was previously created using
a different set of credentials. Use a different computer name, or contact
our administrator to remove any stale conflicting account. The error was:

Access is denied.
```

Here is an example that will provide these permissions for one person.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

# Just add the guids as string variables, just to make the example a little cleaner to read.
# Parsing them as actual GUID objects, so the right constructor will be called.
$accountRestrictionsGuid = [GUID]::Parse('4c164200-20c0-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529')
$resetPasswordGuid = [GUID]::Parse('00299570-246d-11d0-a768-00aa006e0529')
$dnsHostWrite = [GUID]::Parse('72e39547-7b18-11d1-adef-00c04fd8d5cd')
$userAccountControlGuid = [GUID]::Parse('bf967a68-0de6-11d0-a285-00aa003049e2')    
$spnWrite = [GUID]::Parse('f3a64788-5306-11d1-a9c5-0000f80367c1')

# This will get the ACL for the specific computer account you want to allow
# a user to add back to the domain.
$computerDN = 'CN=Test,CN=Computers,DC=domain,DC=com'
$acl = Get-Acl -Path "AD:\$computerDN"

# You need to create an identity reference for each group/user you want to add permissions for.
$adAccount = New-Object System.Security.Principal.NTAccount 'domain.com','userName'

# Create and add these 4 rules for EVERY user or group you want to give these permissions.
# So, 2 users, you will have 8 rules.
# We are using the following overload for the constructor: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cawwkf0x(v=vs.110).aspx
# Note that no where in these rules, you are not referring to computer objects directly, but to properties of the computer objects.
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $adAccount,'ReadProperty,WriteProperty','Allow',$accountRestrictionsGuid,'None'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $adAccount,'ReadProperty,WriteProperty','Allow',$userAccountControlGuid,'None'))
# The Self permission is the permission for a validated right.
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $adAccount,'Self','Allow',$dnsHostWrite,'None'))
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectoryAccessRule $adAccount,'Self','Allow',$spnWrite,'None'))

# Note that this is a different type of object.  The Reset Password right is an extended right, 
# and as such we need to create an AD Extended Right Access Rule.
# The constructor we are using is https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfcetwbe(v=vs.110).aspx
$acl.AddAccessRule((New-Object System.DirectoryServices.ExtendedRightAccessRule $adAccount,'Allow',$resetPasswordGuid,'None'))

# Set the permissions back to the object
Set-ACl -Path "AD:\$computerDN" -AclObject $acl
```